# Adding shell variable to file path in Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifact

I am writing a pipeline script in Jenkins, I have created a directory based on the `$BUILD_NUMBER*` environment variable using shell script by `sh 'mkdir build/$BUILD_NUMBER'`.

Now I want to artifact the zipfile I created into this **BUILD_NUMBER** folder. So I have written the below code:

```
zip zipFile: 'build/ResultsApp.zip', archieve: false, dir:'/Users/username/.jenkins/ProjectName/build/$BUILD_NUMBER'**
archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'build/$BUILD_NUMBER/ResultsApp.zip'
```

I am getting an error as `/Users/username/.jenkins/ProjectName/build/$BUILD_NUMBER"` does not exist. I have earlier created the BUILD_NUMBER folder using mkdir, but in `dir` option its not recognizing the BUILD_NUMBER Folder which I have created earlier.

$BUILD_NUMBER is not recognized as already created "number", instead recognizing as $BUILD_NUMBER name itself.

Can anyone tell me what have I written wrong?

Comment: The answer can be found in [Groovy string interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation): _Any Groovy expression can be interpolated in all string literals, apart from single and triple-single-quoted strings._

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the {}, the variable should look like:

> archiveArtifacts artifacts: "logs_${params.ENVIRONMENT}.tar.gz",
> fingerprint: true

that worked for me, hope it helps others too